# Angular: Change classes of elements by clicking one, inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

There is `ng-repeat` and in there are many li's. The superior li's are visible, while the minor ones are not displayed. By clicking on one superior li, the minor should get visible/invisible. All li's are equated in their code, means there is no embedding code which purport who is superior or minor. They are only distinguishable by id. A superior li's has the id 1, while a minor get's the id 1.1.

```
<li class="list-table" ng-repeat="row in rows" id="{{row.first}}.{{row.second}}" ng-click="toggle_rows(row)")
   <div style="list-cell">
    <p>{{row.first}}</p>
    <p>{{row.second}}</p>
    <p>{{row.name}}</p>
   <div>
</li>
```

I tried several things but got stuck. Any advice appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to determine what you need to accomplish from the posted code sample, can you add some more HTML to your question?

Comment: @kmdsax http://jsfiddle.net/fctCG/1/. Yes you're right, hope that explains it better.

Comment: I could find a solution on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/u75us/) but for that I had to make the html-code nested. So the li's were not anymore equated.